# Добавление данных из выборки + статичный столбец (Access)

Tags: sql, access

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в рамках одного sql - запроса (используется Access) можно осуществить добавление записей в таблицу, полученных выборкой из другой таблицы, добавив к данным один статичный столбец.

На примере. Есть массив данных чата, в нем мы ищем определенные сообщения с ключевыми словами (например, "прокуратура", "минздрав", "дпс"). Полученные сообщения (дату, id клиента) необходимо добавить в накопительную таблицу, указав, какое именно слово было найдено. Так как для "облака тегов" представлено не много ключевых слов, было решено сделать несколько запросов - каждый для своего слова.

```
INSERT INTO Claim (Customer_ID, Date_time)
SELECT DISTINCT Автор, [Дата сообщения]
FROM Hist LEFT JOIN Claim on (Hist.[Дата сообщения]=Claim.Date_time)
WHERE ((Hist.[Сообщения] LIKE "*прокуратур*") AND (Hist.[Автор] NOT LIKE "Оператор*]) And Claim.ID IS NULL);
```

В этом коде мы добавляем в накопительную таблицу (Claim) уникальных авторов и даты из таблицы-выгрузки (Hist), удостоверившись в отсутствии пересечений с ранее добавленными данными посредством Left join-а.

Вопрос. Как в рамках этого же запроса добавить в Claim.Key_words значение "Прокуратура"?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Claim (Key_words, Customer_ID, Date_time)
SELECT DISTINCT 'Прокуратура', Автор, [Дата сообщения]
и далее
```